# iOS auto layout ios7 vs ios8

Tags: ios, constraints, autoresizingmask, ios-autolayout

What exactly are the improvements in auto layout ios 7 and ios 8?

My app is working fine in ios 8 but has different behavior in ios7. Constraints are breaking in ios 7 after loading views multiple times.

I want to know what are the things that ios 8 now handles which ios7 autolayout cannot do before.

Like how iOS 7 and iOS 8 handles "manually added subviews" with autoresizing masks ( Flexible width and Flexible height )

Thanks!!

**im not using size classes and relative to margin

Comment: Refer : http://mobileoop.com/auto-layout-advanced-techniques-for-ios-8-and-7-using-xcode-6-on-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Working with autolayout in iOS 7 and iOS 8 is the same. Adaptive layout is really just an umbrella term for all the new layout tools in Xcode 6 and iOS 8-- one of which being Autolayout. Though autolayout isn't new, it's still a part of the adaptive layout toolset, and it's much improved in iOS 8. Other adaptive layout tools include Size Classes and Adaptive Fonts. I recommend reading this Ray Wenderlich article that has some examples of the new tools: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: I'm not using size classes

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed my ios7 issues by these:

1. avoid constraints to margin and size classes,
2. avoid constraints with "aspect ratio"
3. avoid proportional height and width which conflicts with some push/pop/present dismiss animation in ios 7